# Viewing all the File Handling Methods and all the types of Errors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, methods, error-handling

How would I be able to write a code that I can use to see all of the File Methods like `close(), detach(), readline(), readlines() ...`  in python 3. I also want to have another code that shows all the possible `errors` like `ArithmeticError, AssertionError, MemoryError ...`. I am trying to use `dir()` to be able to list the intended outputs but was unsuccessful so far. How would I go about coding or these?

Comment: The best way to do this is by reading the documentation. The python runtime isn't really organized for easy searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a file and use `dir()` on the open file object.  Remove the entries starting with `_` as they are typically implementation details.  If you only want callable methods use `getattr` to look up the attribute in the object and `callable` to see if it is a method. There will be slightly different lists depending on the mode the file is opened with.

```
>>> t = open('x.txt', 'w')   # text mode
>>> b = open('y.txt', 'wb')  # binary mode
>>> print('\n'.join(x for x in dir(t) if callable(getattr(t, x)) and not x.startswith('_')))
close
detach
fileno
flush
isatty
read
readable
readline
readlines
reconfigure
seek
seekable
tell
truncate
writable
write
writelines
>>> print('\n'.join(x for x in dir(b) if callable(getattr(b, x)) and not x.startswith('_')))
close
detach
fileno
flush
isatty
read
read1
readable
readinto
readinto1
readline
readlines
seek
seekable
tell
truncate
writable
write
writelines
```

For errors, the following works:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(x for x in dir(__builtins__) if x.endswith('Error')))
ArithmeticError
AssertionError
AttributeError
BlockingIOError
BrokenPipeError
BufferError
ChildProcessError
ConnectionAbortedError
ConnectionError
ConnectionRefusedError
ConnectionResetError
EOFError
EnvironmentError
FileExistsError
FileNotFoundError
FloatingPointError
IOError
ImportError
IndentationError
IndexError
InterruptedError
IsADirectoryError
KeyError
LookupError
MemoryError
ModuleNotFoundError
NameError
NotADirectoryError
NotImplementedError
OSError
OverflowError
PermissionError
ProcessLookupError
RecursionError
ReferenceError
RuntimeError
SyntaxError
SystemError
TabError
TimeoutError
TypeError
UnboundLocalError
UnicodeDecodeError
UnicodeEncodeError
UnicodeError
UnicodeTranslateError
ValueError
WindowsError
ZeroDivisionError
```